# Resize arbitrary innerHTML including absolute position tag

Tags: html, css

Looking for a solution that will allow generating any arbitrary HTML and resize the output dynamically using only a wrapper

this is meant to use in a python function something like:

```py
wrapper = """
<body>
  <div id="view" style='width: %dpx; height: %dpx'>
   %s
  </div>
</body>
"""
def wrap(width: int, height: int, content: str):
  return wrapper % (width, height, content)

with open("input.html","r") as f:
   content = f.read()

width = int(input())
height = int(input())

with open("output.html","w") as f:
   f.write(wrap(width, height, content)
```

The main problem is the input.html file may contain position: absolute elements.

something like:

```
<img src="<url>" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; right: 100px">
<img src="<url>" style="position: absolute; top: 400px; right: 300px">
```

The input file is generated from an image.

Comment: So where is the actual "resizing" part, in that code you have shown? Looks to me, as if you are simply sticking the content into a wrapper with a different width & height set ...? Maybe you should go and look into [`scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale())

Comment: Basically, I want to set the size of the content inside the div to be the width and height of the div exactly- this doesn't work because of the position: absolute. The code attempts to show that I need a solution where the resize is wrapped over a given unkown HTML script

Comment: Problem with scale requires for me to know the size beforehand

Comment: If you really want to do it this way, then you will probably have to loop over the elements, and _calculate_ the new position values. But margins, paddings etc. might also influence element positions ...